# What game is in this Alienware advertisement?

Tags: game-identification

I just ordered a new laptop (not Alienware!  (I hate them)), but I was comparing the weight of my new laptop to the weight of my friends Alienware and I really liked the look of the game that they use in their advertisement.

Does anyone know what it is?

Here is the photo:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Decided to turn my comment into an answer.

The first picture you posted was a picture of Vector from Resident Evil: Operation Raccoon City. You can find a description and picture of him [here](http://residentevil.wikia.com/VECTOR). Additionally, if you search for "Resident Evil Vector" in Google images, you'll see a plethora of images of him.

The second picture is also from this game, although I'm having trouble verifying this with a reference or image. This is the best I could find (which also has Vector).
[image]

Edit:

[Here's](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Christine_Yamata) the info on Christine Yamata, the person in the second picture, also from Operation Raccoon City.

Comment: Ha, we found exactly the same image.  I wonder if we googled [the same thing](https://www.google.com/search?q=Resident+Evil:+Operation+Raccoon+City+asian&tbm=isch)? :P

Comment: Nope. I added the word "Woman" to that. You actually did better than me on the search: yours was on page 2, but my wasn't until 4.

Comment: My answer was also a few minutes earlier, but you got all the upvotes :(

Comment: This just made my day.  I love resident evil.  Very happy to find out that this game with awesome looking characters and graphics is part of the series.

Comment: @BlueRaja People probably took pity on my pathetic 58 points up until that point and thought I needed it more.

Answer (score 17):

They are characters from Resident Evil: Operation Raccoon City

[image]

The first actually comes directly from the [promotional images](http://gamerant.com/resident-evil-operation-raccoon-city-screenshots-trung-78910/) they released.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I did notice that @SocioMatt posted a comment that actually had the right answer in it 10 minutes before this answer was posted.  So that's why I have him best answer (I still up-voted your answer though because it is correct).